# (a / b) mod p for large a and b

Tags: modular-arithmetic, big-numbers

i get stuck in finding $(a / b) \bmod p$
what i did is googled and saw some theories and i did
$(a/b) \bmod p = ((a \bmod p) * (((b^{\,p - 2} \bmod p)) \bmod p)) \bmod p$
where $p$ is prime number $(10^9+7)$

but i am still getting wrong answer.
i used divide and conquer to find $b^{\,p-2}$ as below:

```
ll m=1000000007;
ll power(ll x,  ll y,  ll m)
{
    if (y == 0)
        return 1;
    ll p = power(x, y/2, m) % m;
    p = (p * p) % m;

    return (y%2 == 0)? p : (x * p) % m;
}
```

and called the function `power(b,m-2,m);`
and finally compute the result as `((a%m)*(power(b,m-2,m)%m))%m`

but i am still getting wrong answer.
please help me finding what i am doing wrong.
thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should ask on Codeforces.

Comment: if both $a$ and $b$ are large then $a/b$ should be relatively small

Comment: actually i have to calculate a as it is not pregiven. a=(x^y)%m where x and y are very large and x^y cant be sored directly so iuse same above function to generate a i.e a=power(x,y,m)

Comment: You can get line breaks by adding two spaces on the end of a line. Other guidance on formatting is at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @vasya this is modular arithmetic, so $a/b$ means $a\cdot b^{-1}$, where  $b^{-1}$ is another integer not a reciprocal.

Comment: I tried out your code with the appropriate minor modifications in python and it works fine. So it must be a language issue.

Comment: you modified which part of the logic.

Comment: Can a or b be negative? if it is so then that can be the problem, in C "a%m" is not the same as $a \mod m$ when a is negative

Comment: no  both  are  positive .  i  used  it  in  c++.

Comment: What test values of $a$ and $b$ are you using, and what result?

Comment: i am using this trick to calculate a geometric progression in a programming.   first term is k and common ratio is k and no of terms is n where k and n can be anything in between 2 to 10^9.   so i used this trick as res=((power(k,n)-1)*power(k-1,m-2))%m for calculating my G.P result.  but it is giving wrong answer

Comment: power function is as defined above to calculate power in log(n) order of time complexity.

Comment: @Anukulgaurav I didn't modify the logic at all, just translated it into python syntax (so, for example, `return (y%2 == 0)? p : (x * p) % m;` becomes `return p if (y%2==0) else (x*p)%m`).